# Java - Simple networked game is extremly laggy

Tags: java, networking, lag

*I already asked this on codereview a day ago but I haven't got any responses yet, so I though I'd try to ask it here.*

**Let me tell you what I'm trying to make:**

A window pops up asking the user if they want to run a server, or a client. Choosing server will start a server on the LAN. Choosing client will try to connect to that server. Once a server is running and a client has connected, a window pops up with two squares. Both the server/client can move their square with the arrow-keys.

**This is what I'm getting:**

The square for the server moves at the wanted speed, but his movement is very choppy on the side of the client. The clients square, on the other hand, seems to move at about 3 pixels per second (way too slow).

**This is what I'm asking:**

I guess my question is pretty obvious. All I'm doing is sending 2 integers over the internet. Modern online games send **much** more data than this, and they hardly lag, so obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what?

**Server.java:**

```
// server class
public class Server {
    // networking objects
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private DataOutputStream clientOutputStream;
    private DataInputStream clientInputStream;
    // game objects
    private Vec2D serverPos, clientPos;
    private GameManager gameManager;
    // run method
    public void run() {
        // intialization try-catch block 
        try {
            // setup sockets
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            // setup I/O streams
            clientOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch(IOException e) { Util.err(e); }
        // declare & intialize data exchange thread
        Thread dataExchange = new Thread( 
            new Runnable() {
                // run method
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // I/O try-catch block
                    try {
                        // exchange-loop
                        while(true) {
                            // write x & y, flush
                            synchronized(gameManager) {
                                clientOutputStream.writeInt(serverPos.x);
                                clientOutputStream.writeInt(serverPos.y);
                                clientOutputStream.flush();
                            }
                            // read x & y
                            clientPos.x = clientInputStream.readInt();
                            clientPos.y = clientInputStream.readInt();
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) { Util.err(e); }
                }
            }
        );
        // setup game data
        serverPos = new Vec2D(10, 10);
        clientPos = new Vec2D(300, 300);
        gameManager = new GameManager(serverPos, clientPos, serverPos);
        // start data exchange thread
        dataExchange.start();
        // start main loop
        while(true) {
            // get keyboard input
            synchronized(gameManager) {    
                gameManager.update();
            }
            // repaint, sleep
            gameManager.repaint();
            Util.sleep(15);        
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.java:**

```
// client class
public class Client {
    // networking objects
    private Socket serverConnection;
    private DataOutputStream serverOutputStream;
    private DataInputStream serverInputStream;
    // game objects
    private Vec2D serverPos, clientPos;
    private GameManager gameManager;
    // run method
    public void run() {
        // intialization try-catch block 
        try {
            // setup socket
            serverConnection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.19"), 1111);
            // setup I/O streams
            serverOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(serverConnection.getOutputStream());
            serverInputStream = new DataInputStream(serverConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch(IOException e) { Util.err(e); }
        // declare & intialize data exchange thread
        Thread dataExchange = new Thread( 
            new Runnable() {
                // run method
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // I/O try-catch block
                    try {
                        // exchange-loop
                        while(true) {
                            // read x & y
                            synchronized(gameManager) {
                                serverPos.x = serverInputStream.readInt();
                                serverPos.y = serverInputStream.readInt();
                            }
                            // write x & y, flush
                            serverOutputStream.writeInt(clientPos.x);
                            serverOutputStream.writeInt(clientPos.y);
                            serverOutputStream.flush();
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) { Util.err(e); }
                }
            }
        );
        // setup game data
        serverPos = new Vec2D(10, 10);
        clientPos = new Vec2D(300, 300);
        gameManager = new GameManager(serverPos, clientPos, clientPos);
        // start data exchange thread
        dataExchange.start();
        // start main loop
        while(true) {
            // get keyboard input
            synchronized(gameManager) {    
                gameManager.update();
            }
            // repaint, sleep
            gameManager.repaint();
            Util.sleep(15);  
        }
    }
}
```

I got rid of a bunch of the code - I hope it isn't confusing now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question has quite a bit of code. For better help sooner, post a [SSCCE (link)](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Doorknob I got rid of some of the stuff that I don't think is nessesary.

Comment: the TCP is the issue i think ,it got lot of acknowledgement , that is why it takes too much time , use UDP , amen :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Sockets, maybe you see it being laggy for a real time conversation because they are built in over TCP wich has to acknowledge the message and keep pinging to see if the connection is still alive.

Maybe you should use DatagramSocket, that work on UDP protocol. The difference is that UDP just spits stuff without the bother of keeping the connection alive or even trying to know if the message arrived.

example of use: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

Edit: Why don't you try sending that int only when the position in the server changes? Probably the server is sending so much ints that your client has a buffer full of the same values and as you read int by int instead of emptying the buffer you have the fake sensation of being laggy.

Comment: Will that make all the difference though? It's *really* laggy now, and I have trouble believing all that I would have to do is change the protocol.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 I don't see anything wrong, even for just a TCP conn shouldn't be that slow... Is that IP a direct connection? Also what modern games usually do is interpolate data and animate the inbetween gaps.

Comment: I guess I made an asssumption about how modern games do their networking.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by *Is that IP a direct connection?*

Comment: Delivery of the UDP packets is not guaranteed, so expect lost messages.

Comment: Or! What it could be is that you are sending lots of repeated ints and you are not emptying the buffer in the client every time you read.

Comment: @Khanser How would I empty that buffer?

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 Here is the API> http://goo.gl/Am5OI You can either loop your readInt calls till you got an EOF exception, or you can call the read(byte[]) method with a nice buffer, create a nio ByteBuffer object with that byte array, call ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer method and read the ints from there :)

Comment: @Khanser That I will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read all of the code, but I did notice that the "client" and "server" both have threads that read and write updates in a tight loop.

There are three problems with this:

- There is no point the client (or server) telling the other end the current position if it hasn't changed.
- Because the client and server both rigidly "write then read then write then ..." the two threads get into lock-step, and each write / read cycle requires a network round trip.
- You are doing part of the work while holding a lock, and there is another thread grabbing the same lock and doing a screen update.

So you need to arrange that:

- a position update is only sent when the position actually changes, and
- the reading and writing happen on different threads.

@cyroxx has identified another problem that will also result in lagginess.

Comment: Good advice, thanks. I'll do these things you suggested, I see how they could improve performace.

Answer (score 2):

A problem in your code are the `while(true)` loops:

```
    while(true) {
        // get keyboard input
        synchronized(gameManager) {    
            gameManager.update();
        }
        // repaint, sleep
        gameManager.repaint();
        Util.sleep(15);        
    }
```

This way, you are sending either too many updates (when nobody presses a key) or too few updates (because you always wait 15 milliseconds, no matter what happens). It would be better if you listened for keyboard events and if there is one, propagate it to the other side - the other side can then update as a reaction to this "change" event. You might find the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) useful for implementing this.

Comment: I'll try that as well as the things other people suggested.